# Java: When creating an object, why isn't the interface on the right hand side?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, linked-list

```
java.util.Queue<TreeNode> queue = new java.util.LinkedList<TreeNode>();
```

LinkedList implements Queue. Shouldn't Queue be on the right side of the above statement and LinkedList the left?

Comment: No, `Queue` is an interface; `LinkedList` is an implementation.

Comment: Why? What do you think `new Queue()` means?

Comment: `Queue` is a data structure that allows pushing data to one end and getting data from the other end. There are many ways to implement a structure that displays this kind of behavior: `LinkedList` is one.

Comment: @trashgod I am a beginner in Java. I know Queue is an interface and LinkedList has implemented it. The class which implements the interface creates object right? So, that's why I thought LinkedList should have been on the other side

Comment: I may see your confusion.  You might be thinking 'when I say "int i;" I'm asking for i to be implemented as an int; so how can the Queue be on the left.  That's not quite it though. The left is the type/behavior you need. What you assign to it is what is concrete. So in your case 'queue' needs to look like a Queue; and you are assigning to it (or initializing it with) the concrete type LinkedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can assign a value to a variable of the same type or a more general type. In your example, `new LinkedList<TreeNode>()` is a value. Since `LinkedList` *implements* `Queue`, it's more specific than `Queue`. i.e. A `LinkedList` **is a** `Queue`.

For instance, all three of these are valid

```
Object o = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
LinkedList<TreeNode> list = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
```

But you can't write any of these because they're incorrect assignment.

```
LinkedList<TreeNode> o = new Object();
LinkedList<TreeNode> queue = new Queue<TreeNode>();
```

P.S. the second one in that example is also invalid because Queue is an interface, and you can't instantiate (`new`) an interface because it's not a concrete type

Comment: On you first line, don't you mean a more *specific* type, not a more *general* type? You can assign a Dog object (specific) to an Animal variable (general) but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

The example declares `queue` to be a reference to an object having the type of `Queue<TreeNode>`, but the variable must refer to an instance of a concrete implementation of that interface, `LinkedList<TreeNode>`. By [*coding to the interface*](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html), you agree to use only the methods of `Queue`. This allows you to change the implementation if required, without changing how `queue` is used.